# Trouble changing my java version on my IDE (eclipse Mars.2)

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm having trouble changing my java version. Always been using the default one: 1.8.0, and wanted to update but its not letting me.

[image]

This is my CLASSPATH:

[image]

And this is my PATH (I highlighted all the Java related stuff):

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Your JRE home should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin. You have to give it path to bin directory.

Comment: Okay, that was my bad, should have posted the image with the correct path, but still, it gives me an error. http://prntscr.com/xgt52f

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/mars/ is not the latest, so probably has problems with java 15. Download a newer version (best when settings are okay on java 1.8). And then try

Comment: Eclipse Mars is 13 releases and 5 years behind and Java 15 was released at the end of last year. Your retro Eclipse does not support the current Java version and does not run with the current Java version you have.

Comment: Yeah, you are both right. My version of eclipse was so damn old, it couldn't handle Java 15. Downloaded the latest version and now I can change between java versions. I have no excuse for my mental "oops" right there (didn't even think the IDE was the problem). Thanks for the help.